# Очистка содержимого сайта от лишней html разметки

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Чищу собранный сайт от всего лишнего. И вот попалась не очень удобная ситуация.
Не пойму что поместить в квери селектор. Чищу примерно так:

```
document.QuerySelector("div.mod_user_menu").Remove();
document.QuerySelector("#main_menu").Remove();
```

Первый вариант, цепляюсь за класс, 2 вариант цепляюсь за id. А тут так написано что не знаю за что бы зацепиться. Кто нибудь может подсказать? Не классов, не айдишников нет. Есть только атрибуты.

Comment: А что удалить здесь хотите?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev банально, но всего 1 строчку) всё остальное потом почиститься с помощью текст контекста, но сейчас я вырезаю кусками под конкретный сайт лишний текст. И в данном случае это строчка "Скачать и печатать" может по ссылке как то можно? Типо a."ссылка". Типо как под класс. Но не уверен.

Comment: Можно например так: `a[href*='print']` по тексту `print` в ссылке

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, уже добавил ответ. Поглядите его, по моему почти то же самое.

Comment: Да, почти, но в моем варианте будет работать на похожие ссылки, например если на другой странице `proschai-1-klas.html` будет другим

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev `document.QuerySelector("a[href*=\"Сайт\"]").Remove();` Вот так вы имеете в виду?

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev и тогда мне очистит все сайты которые идут после тега a?

Comment: нет, `*` даёт возможность в этом случае просто указывать не весь урл, просто сработает если в урле содержится контент который указан дальше.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev да уже попробовал. Спасибо за предложение. Если не сложно оформите свой вариант тоже как ответ.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev а как тогда нужно удалять абсолютно все ссылки? то есть все строки где начинается с тега a и потом идёт href= и абсолютно всё равно какой будет сайт?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` - получите массив всех ссылок, потом циклом их все удаляете.

Answer (score 0):

Нашлось решение проблемы:

```
document.QuerySelector("[href=\"Сайт\"]").Remove();
```

Это выбор строки с атрибутом который указывается в квадратных скобках.